# Multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, for-loop, range-based-loop

I was curious about why we go through a multidimensional array this way

```
for (auto& row : mat1)
    {
        for (int& elements : row)
        {
            cin >> elements;
        }
    }
```

Why do we use &(pass by ref) when we make a temp variable called elements that goes through the rows and gets each value. aswell as the & in the for (auto& row : mat1)  Can someone explain this whole part with every detail please ?

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int row{ 3 }, col{ 3 };
    array<array<int, col>, row > mat1;
    cout << "Enter matrix 1 elements: ";
    for (auto& row : mat1)
    {
        for (int& elements : row)
        {
            cin >> elements;
        }
    }
    for (auto& row : mat1)
    {
        for (int& elements : row)
            cout << elements << "  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use references, then you will make *copies* of the data.

And if you make a copy (iterate by *value*) rather than using references, you will only modify the local copy, not the original data.

This is for the input loop of course, where you have

```
cin >> elements;
```

In the output loop there's no need for references for the `int` elements themselves, but I recommend using `const` references for the arrays since otherwise you make a copy which could be expensive.

So in the output loop to:

```
for (auto const& row : mat1)
{
    for (auto element : row)
    {
        std::cout << element;
    }
}
```

Comment: wooops sorry    ;)